# Django test will not notice "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"

Tags: python, django, templates, pytest

I'm writing a basic django test for a forms.Form type page. Here is the form:

```
# This is the form to become a seller
class BecomeSellerForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
email = forms.EmailField(min_length=3, max_length=20)
phone_number = forms.IntegerField(max_value=19999999999)
```

My test consists of a basic post request and I asser my response status code is 200. However, my I get this error in my test:

```
ValueError: modules context processor require "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"to be in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings file.
```

And it's getting caught in the successful return statement in my views.py code:

```
return render(request, 'accounts/become_seller_success.html', context)
```

What confuses me is that I  100% have met this requirement in my settings file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates', ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

So why is my test fussing about it? I have been looking around but have not seen a problem/solution that is similar. Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: Please show the failing test and the complete traceback

Comment: The error is also referring to a "modules" context processor, which isn't listed. Are you sure you don't have another setting somewhere?

Comment: The error looks as if it is from [this app](https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/master/material/frontend/context_processors.py) but you don't mention it anywhere in your question. The error message looks incorrect - `request.user` would be set by the auth *middleware*, not the context processor.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Long story short - when using a RequestFactory - you should set the request.user to something. Setting to none works.

```
request.user = None
```

Adding that before I made the call fixes everything and when I use it to test my permissions code it works as expected too.

Thanks for the tip @Alasdair